# Framework for a easy and fast photo gallery

Tags: php, frameworks, gallery, photo

I need to develop a web photo gallery or find one.
This photo gallery has to be really simple, fast and easy to use.
The features I need are just: upload image, tag image, search, download, preview, divide in albums.
I already tried some galleries like Zenphoto, Gallery, but are to slow to use and there are too many steps.
Can you suggest me a good way to do this with a framework or a gallery that already exist in opensource.
Thanks

**EDIT**

Thanks for all your proposals, but none of them satisfy me. In the end I opted to develop one myself using yii framework.

Here is a quick [demo](http://www.pietroghezzi.ch/gallery)

Comment: You may testdrive some here: http://php.opensourcecms.com/scripts/show.php?catid=7&category=Image%20Galleries

Comment: I recently worked with Piwigo (http://www.piwigo.org).

Comment: Gallery 3 (http://gallery.menalto.com/) is also an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

Piwigo (piwigo.org), it has all the features you ask and hundreds of plugins for additional features. You can write your own theme and plugins. You can add photos on an advanced web form, with FTP, with iPhone/Android or remote softwares like Lightroom, Digikam or Shotwell.

Comment: Hi Pierrick, does Piwigo supports OpenID. This is a killer-feature that makes the difference! Thank you for your investment on the powerful and libre Piwigo ;)

Comment: Hi oHessling, no Piwigo does not support OpenID for now. But I agree, this would be an interesting feature.

Comment: @olibre I noticed [this extension](http://piwigo.org/ext/index.php) which lists OpenID amongst its supported services